# Incorrect Number of probabilities simulating a Markov chain

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov

my transition probability matrix is like this

```
             BP          IP             SP 


BPBP     0.4586757     0.3772354     0.1640889

IPBP     0.3489484     0.4746654     0.1763862

SPBP     0.3756522     0.4162319     0.2081159

BPIP     0.3646061     0.4640000     0.1713939

IPIP     0.2666122     0.5654956     0.1678922

SPIP     0.3054187     0.4860427     0.2085386

BPSP     0.4125561     0.3974215     0.1900224

IPSP     0.2974337     0.5069415     0.1956247

SPSP     0.3576642     0.4333942     0.2089416
```

and the code to simulate a first order MC from it is

```
  function(trans,initprob,N)
  {
  BrokerPosition <- c("BP", "IP", "SP")
  mysequence<-character()
  firstposition <- sample(BrokerPosition, 1, rep=TRUE, prob=initprob)
  mysequence[1]   <- firstposition
  for (i in 2:N){
   prevposition <- mysequence[i-1]
   probabilities  <- trans[,prevposition]
   BPosition<- sample(BrokerPosition, 1, rep=TRUE, prob=probabilities)
   mysequence[i]  <- BPosition
                }
  return(mysequence)
  }
```

but since this is a non square matrix I am getting an error of mismatch of probabilities ,any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 2):

You are using your transition matrix in the wrong direction:
try with

```
trans[ paste( mysequence[c(i-2,i-1)], collapse="" ), ]
```

An alternative would be to to convert your second order Markov chain into a first order one:
for instance, the states after 
IPBP would be BPIP, BPBP, BPSP (and the other ones, IP* and SP*, would have zero probabilities).
The transition matrix is then a 9*9 matrix with a lot of zeroes.

Comment: Hi, your first suggestion concatenates two states into one state ,but what I am trying to do is use the state at t-1 and t-2 to estimate the probable state at t ,so the output will a first order MC like BP->IP->SP->SP->IP etc , and if understand your second suggestion since some of the transition probabilities become zero will not that make the MC non ergodic

Comment: `function(trans,initposition,N)`

   `{`


       `mysequence<-character()`

  `Firstposition<-initposition`

`index<-grep(Firstposition,row.names(trans))`

 `for(j in 1:ncol(trans)){`
    

`probabilities[j]<-c(trans[index,j])`

 `}`

 `for(i in 1:N){`

  `BPosition<-sample(colnames(trans),1,rep=TRUE,prob=probabilities)`

  `mysequence[i]<-BPosition`

           `  } `
`return(mysequence)`

 `}`
`,

Comment: (I had forgotten a comma in my answer, which made it unclear.)
To simulate from your Markov chain, you need the conditional probabilities
`P[ x[n+1] | x[n]=a, x[n-1]=b ]`: for `a` and `b` given,
that is a row in your transition matrix (your were extracting columns).
Contrary to what I had initially written,
after transforming the Markov chain to a first order one, it is not block-diagonal 
-- it has as many zeroes as a block-diagonal matrix, 
but not in the same positions.
In particular, it remains ergodic.